# How to select multiple checkbox in reactjs?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, checkbox

The problem is that I need to pass array of object , I can not get my accepted data .My accepted data will be this format. However, user can remove by using unchecked.

```
 {

    notification : {group:["can_view","can_create", "can_delete","can_update","can_upload","can_download"],
    topGroup:["can_view","can_create", "can_delete","can_update","can_upload","can_download"}
    }

  handleAllChecked = (id, role, data) => event => {
    let fruites = this.state.fruites;
    fruites
      .filter(f => f.groupId === id)
      .forEach(fruite => {
        if (event.target.checked === true) {
          fruite.isChecked = event.target.checked;

          console.log(data);
        } else {
          fruite.isChecked = false;
        }
      });

    this.setState({ fruites: fruites });
  };
```

here is my codesanbox , You can easily understand 
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-http-v35lf

Comment: Please explain in more details what output is desired

Comment: if you want to select checkbox "group" or "top group" and accordingly their children checkboxes to be selected, I guess you have a typo in the code change const { listofdata } = this.state;
    const newList = [...listofdata]; to const { fruites } = this.state;
    const newList = [...fruites];

Comment: can you change its . I faced an error

Comment: Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Forexample , When user click on group, data format  will be this format {group:["can_view","can_create"]} and when user click on top group {group:["can_view","can_create],topgroup:["can_view","can_create"]}

Comment: I actually want to get this format of data

Comment: even when they unchecked data will be removed